# Rx: emit value after the source observable emits

Tags: angular, rxjs

There is the method that has a signature with `Observable<item>` as a return value (actually it is part of resolver from Angular 2). But before the method begin to get `item` instance it need to get some id from other observable.

```
export class itemResolve implements Resolve<item>{
    constructor(
        private itemService: ItemService, //service for access to item instance
        private idService: IdService //service for access to id
    ){}

    resolve() {
        return this.idService.getId().<...>(id => this.itemService.getItem(id)); //???
    }
}
```

idService.getId() returns Observable. How can I waiting for id and continue to get item by id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `mergeMap` operator:

```
resolve() {
    return this.idService.getId()
      .mergeMap.(id => this.itemService.getItem(id));
}
```

Demo here: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html

`switchMap`:

> Map to observable, complete previous inner observable, emit values.

This mean, it'll complete previous observable, emit, switch to new observable.

> If only one inner subscription should be active at a time

if only one inner observable, `mergeMap` and `concatMap` are the same.

Comment: How is this different from `switchMap`?

Comment: `switchMap` will `This operator can cancel in-flight network requests!` previous observable